# Angular Formly Model with complex object

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I'm using Angular Formly and works very well if the model is a value of the scope, like a string:

```
{
    key: 'name',
    type: 'input'
}
```

The problem is that I'm using a more elaborated object to handle the model, with "controller as" syntax and the name as part of the user object:

```
vm.user = {name: 'john', lastname: 'doe'}
```

And then of course, the key would be:

```
{
    key: 'user.name',
    type: 'input'
}
```

(Usually the vm is taken out of the key in formly notation).

The problem is that Formly uses a bracketed notation to handle the model:

```
template = '<input ng-model=\"model[options.key]\">'
```

That when processed, spits out this output:

```
<input name="bd.form_input_user.name_1" type="text" ng-model="model.user.name">
```

Of course, the model doesn't have the user object and empty fields show.

So, my question is: How can I pass or link the appropriate object to the formly model when it's a more complex object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model can be defined both at the form and the field level, so it is easy to use any property in an object graph as a form field. An example:

Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
    <formly-form model="vm.data" fields="vm.userFields">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.submit(vm.user)">Submit</button>
    </formly-form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', ['formly', 'formlyBootstrap'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.data = {
        user: {
            name: 'john',
            lastname: 'doe'
        },
        extra: 'extra'
    };

    vm.userFields = [
        {
        model: vm.data.user,
        key: 'name',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
            type: 'text',
            label: 'Name',
            placeholder: 'Enter name'
            }
        },
        {
        model: vm.data.user,
        key: 'lastname',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
            type: 'text',
            label: 'Lastname',
            placeholder: 'Enter lastname'
            }
        },
        {
        key: 'extra',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
            type: 'text',
            label: 'Extra',
            placeholder: 'Enter extra'
        }}
    ];
}]);
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/c37gxg3h/

Comment: Perfect! Elegant and simple

Comment: Note, in this example, you could alternatively omit the `model` property and instead specify the `key` as: `user.name`